# Efficient Dictionary change value or add (key,value) if not in dictionary

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary

Suppose I have a Dictionary`<TKey, TValue`>, where TValue is a reference type.

I want to assign TValue myNewValue to the element with TKey myKey. If there is no element with myKey, I want to add it.

I want to do this efficiently with a minimal GetHashCode():

```
private void AddOrReplace(TKey key, TValue value)
{
    Dictionary<TKey, TValue> myDictionary = GetMyDictionary(...);
    TValue existingValue;
    if (myDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out existingValue))
    {   // key already in dictionary
        existingValue = value;
    }
    else
    {   // key not in dictionary yet
        myDictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

This way, TKey.GetHashCode() is called once if the key already exist, but it is called twice if the key must be added.

However this wouldn't work if TValue is a value type

```
existingValue = value; // wrong! won't change the value in the dictionary
```

Code ought to be something like:

```
private void AddOrReplace(TKey key, int value)
{
    Dictionary<TKey, int> myDictionary = GetMyDictionary(...);
    if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(key)
    {   // key already in dictionary
        myDictionary.key = value;
    }
    else
    {   // key not in dictionary yet
        myDictionary.Add(key, value);
    }
}
```

This way TKey.GetHashCode() is always called twice.

Isn't there a more efficient method, where TKey.GetHashCode is only called once?

Comment: btw, that also doesn't work if TValue is a reference type.

Comment: What are you trying to solve? GetHashCode is supposed to be fast, not return a unique hash code. It should be a *faster* way to check for *in*equality than a full `Equals` comparison

Comment: Why are you worried about micro-optimizing a `GetHashCode` call? Is this really a bottleneck in your code?

Comment: Also, why not just call `myDict[key]=Value` ?

Comment: Panagiotis is right. To clarify: `myDictionary[key]=value` will replace the value if it exists and add it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Panagiotis and Dennis: You are right, I should use [..]. I should better read the specifications: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Item: the get operation raises exception if key not found, but the set operation CREATES if key not found. Hence I don't have to check for existence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dennis_E and Panagiotis Kanavos provided the answer. **Thanks both of you**.

I just add it here, in case someone thinks he has the same problem.

[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.Item property (TKey)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx) Describes it as follows:

**Property Value**
Type: TValue
The value associated with the specified key.

- **get** If the specified key is not found, a get operation throws a KeyNotFoundException,
- **set** a set operation creates a new element with the specified key.